# How to find a logarithmic function as a fit to my data?

Tags: fitting

My data is:

```
d = {{0, 3.889}, {0.04, 3.941}, {0.06, 5.036}, {0.08, 12.589}, {0.1, 16.972}, {0.2, 13.200}, {0.4, 12.063}};
```

I need to fit a function as: $\log_b a + \log_b [x (1 - x)]$ and obtain the appropriate $a$ and $b$. Also, $0 < x < 1$.

So, I have:

```
FindFit[d, Log[b, a] + Log[b, x (1 - x)], {a, b}, x]
```

But I get several errors, such as: "Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered."

How to overcome these errors?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your data `d`should include the x-values!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your model a little bit.
First data point cann't be used because of `Log[0]`

Try

```
mod = NonlinearModelFit[Rest[d] , {a + b Log[ x (1 - x)], a > 0 }, {a, b }, x,Method -> "NMinimize"] //Quiet
Show[{Plot[mod[x], {x, 0, .4}], ListPlot[d]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you restrict on logarithmic  model?

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann shouldn't you impose restrictions like  $b\neq 1$ and $b>0$?

Comment: @rhermans The original model from question would require these constraints, the model in my answer doesn't need these constraints.